# What does the special variable $@ mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, eval, perlvar

I'm trying to understand the following piece of code:

```
sub foo {
    ...
    if ( $@ ) {
        ...
        die $@;
    }
}
```

Comment: A tip: for the squiggly variables that look like pure punctuation, visit `perldoc perlvar`.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578671/where-can-i-find-information-about-perls-special-variables

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`perldoc -f eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

> If there is a syntax error or runtime
>   error, or a "die" statement is
>   executed, an undefined value is
>   returned by "eval", and $@ is set to
>   the error message. If there was no
>   error, $@ is guaranteed to be a null
>   string.

See also [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Answer (score 3):

`$@` is a magic variable containing the error message of the last `eval` command, if any.

Answer (score 0):

The if loop should be preceded by eval for it to be able to trap $@.

During an eval(), $@ is always set on failure and cleared on success.

In case whr code inside eval() did not compile, $@ is set to the compilation error.