# Where can I find information about Perl's special variables?

Tags: perl, built-in, special-variables

Perl has quite a few special variables such as `@F`, `$!`, `%!` ... etc. Where are all Perl's special variables documented?

Comment: There are already at least three questions about Perl's special variables. The answer to each and every one is the same, see `perldoc perlvar`. I am posting this question so every question of the form *What does special variable `$@%!!~` do in Perl?* can be referred back to this. Of course, those other questions should **NOT** be deleted - just closed.

Comment: the trouble with the non-alphanumeric soup is that it's pretty much non-googleable :( ... and by the time someone is aware of the fact that they need to ask/search for "special variables" or that such a generalization exists, they already wouldn't need to ask the Q. So I don't see any way to actually prevent such quetions for perpetuity, BUT this post should help greatly with answering them!

Comment: @DVK The point is not to prevent them from being asked. In fact, having a question for each variable would be great for indexing. However, there is only one answer to all those questions and therefore they should be closed (**NOT** deleted) with a pointer to this question.

Comment: I don't see how we can help people who aren't aware of the standard perldoc documentation. I would never hire anyone who didn't know that `perldoc perl` gave the index of all entries.

Comment: The organization of the Perl documentation is a mess. There's plenty we can do to help people use it better. Imagine this question as "Where could I find information on creating Perl variables?" Only about a quarter of the people I ask know the answer, and this includes people who know Perl quite well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All special variables used by Perl are documented in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). You can view this document on your computer by running

```
perldoc perlvar
```

The documentation for a specific special variable can also be accessed at the command line using `perldoc -v`:

```
perldoc -v @F
```

You may need to escape/quote some variables to avoid interpolation by your shell:

```
perldoc -v '$!'
```

or

```
perldoc -v "$!"
```

if you are using `cmd.exe`.

For more information:

```
perldoc -h
perldoc perldoc
```

Comment: Oooh, didn't know about that.  Sweet!

Comment: the powers that be decided to lose that feature in the 'perldoc rewrite' in perl 5.9, now it is, 'be verbose'

Answer (score 8):

All special variables used by Perl are documented in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). You can access the version of this documentation that came with your `perl` by entering `perldoc perlvar` on the command line.

Comment: @KennyTM Apparently we posted essentially the same answer at the same time. So I deleted mine and put the extra info in it in your post so there aren't two substantially identical answers.